# Using Promises in Mongoose Routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I understand Promises in JavaScript or atleast I think I do (correct me if Im wrong).

**Create a Promise:**

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  // do something async here

  if(itWorked){

    resolve();

  }else {

    reject();
  }

});
```

**Use a Promise:**

```
promise.then(function(result){

},function(err){

});
```

I have an app based on MEAN Stack and some of my mongoose routes are becoming a callback hell. I want move away from callbacks in mongoose routes and handle them using Promises. But I can't seem to figure out how exactly to do that.

**For example:**

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res){

  User.findOne(_id, function(err, user){
      if(err)
         console.log(err)
      else if(user){

         Receipt.findOne(user.bookName, function(err, book){
           if(err)
            console.log(err)

           else if(book){
             // again do something here
          }  
       })
     }
   })
});
```

**In the above example you can see that the code is getting harder to read and maintain. How can I use Promises here to improve my code?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, first are you using `mongoose` right?

`User` is your mongoose model which responds to methods such as `findOne(query)`, `findOneAndUpdate(query, update, opts)` etc..

After calling any of these methods, call the method `exec()` which returns a Query.

A Query is not exactly a Promise and you'll need to specify which Promises will Mongo use. Here I would recommend to use the native ones so, add this line at your project:

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose')
 mongoose.Promise = Promise
```

Now, this instruction is returning you a Promise, nice!

```
User.findOne(q).exec()
```

You can now create a Promise chain with your logic, for example:

```
 return User
     .findOne(_id)
     .exec()
     .then((user) => {
       return Receipt
         .findOne({ bookName: user.bookName })
         .exec()
       })
     .then((receipt) => {
            // example
            return res.status(200).json(receipt)
         }))
     })
```

Tip: I'd suggest to create aux methods in order to make the code even more cleaner:

```
/** @return {Promise} */
function findUser(id) {
  return User.findOne(id).exec()
}

/** @return {Promise} */
function findReceipt(bookName) {
  return Receipt.findOne({ bookName }).exec()
}

// example
function f(req, res) {
  const userId = req.get('id')

  return findUser(userId)
    .then((user) => findReceipt(user.bookName))
    .then((receipt) => res.status(200).json(receipt))
    .catch((err) => res.status(500).json(null))
}

// register your handler
app.get('/book', f)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I have few questions to clear some concepts. In the line `mongoose.Promise = Promise` are you plugging in the native ES6 promises library into mongoose? And `then` function runs when the `_findUser` promise returns? And I am guessing the term `returning a promise` means whether the `_findUser` function has `resolved` or `rejected`. Am I Right?

Comment: Exactly, `mongoose.Promise = Promise` is telling mongoose to use native ES6 promises; 
chaining promises: `_findUser()` is a heavy task that will return someday the expected user, **when** you have resolved `user` you can start a new task (did you notice the return?) `_findReceipt()`. That's also a heavy task which will return a `receipt`. **when** you have resolved `receipt` your are ready for returning your response. If **ANY** of these tasks raise an error you'll execute your `catch` statement

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining. I understand it mostly now. For some reason I am finding promises quite difficult to get my head around.

Comment: would you tick this answer?