# What the right way to use Promises with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I'm new with Promises and in two days a already saw at least five ways to do.

Some ways are older versions, others focus on other languages, so I decide to ask what should be used today.

I did it this way, with 'err' and 'doc' parameters:

```
Proposals.findById({ ...body, user }, (err, doc) => 
    Advertisements.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id:  body.advertisement}, {$push: {proposals: doc._id}}
    )
)
.then((Proposals) => Proposals.view())
.then(success(res, 201))
.catch(next)
```

And this:

```
Proposals.create({ ...body, user })
.then((Proposals) => {
    Advertisements.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id:  body.advertisement}, {$push: {proposals: Proposals._id}}
    )
    .catch(Advertisements)

    return Proposals.view()
}) 
.then(success(res, 201))
.catch(next)
```

Without the "catch" and "return" itsn't work, but I don't know why exactly. :x

The answer to 
[Using Promises in Mongoose Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860898/using-promises-in-mongoose-routes)
seems like a beautiful but I couldn't reproduce in code above.

```
return findUser(userId)
  .then((user) => findReceipt(user.bookName))
  .then((receipt) => res.status(200).json(receipt))
  .catch((err) => res.status(500).json(null))
```

Are any of these codes more right?
Could you help me to fix the second code?

Thank you.

Comment: How exactly did it not work? Did you get any error messages returned or what way did you expect it to behave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of ways to handle promises in Mongoose. The exact way that you decide to implement it is left to personal preference, but you need to make sure that your order of execution is as expected. In your first example you are mixing a callback with promises, which I personally think is not optimal. The third example is cleaner as it is a chain of promises being passed down via the `then` calls.

The important thing to note is that if you want to run async code inside your `then` calls, you need to ensure you return a `Promise` that resolves at the right moment. In your second example, you are possibly returning before your `findOneAndUpdate` call is finished executing. You can avoid this in a number of ways. One option would be to wrap the second call inside a `Promise`. I give you an idea below by mixing parts of your second and third examples and assuming that the return value from `proposal.view()` is not async. I use explicit `return` statements for clarity.

```js
Proposals.create({ ...body, user })
  .then((proposal) => {
    // call returns a new promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // make second async call to database
      Advertisements.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id:  body.advertisement }, 
        { $push: { proposals: proposal._id } },
      )
      .then(() => {
        // promise resolves here and passes return
        // value of proposal.view() to next `then`
        return resolve(proposal.view())
      });
    });
  })
  // consume the value from proposal.view() and send it in response
  .then(proposal => res.status(200).json(proposal))
  .catch(next)
```

This would mean that the return value of `proposal.view()` will only be passed onto the next `then` once the `findOneAndUpdate` call is complete.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. 
It seemed to me that "findOneAndUpdate" doesn't work without the return at the beginning. That's right?

Comment: If you don't return it or wrap it in a promise that is in turn returned, the next `then` will execute without waiting for `findOneAndUpdate` to return. This means that your `res` will not be passed the result of `findOneAndUpdate` and therefore will not return a document, but the update might occur in the database. Returning it makes the next `then` wait for the promise to resolve before executing.

Answer (score 1):

Let me detail the syntax of the first block of code:

```
Proposals.findById({ ...body, user }, (err, doc) => {
  return Advertisements.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id:  body.advertisement}, {$push: {proposals: doc._id}}
  );
})
.then((Proposals) => { return Proposals.view() })
.then(success(res, 201))
.catch(next)
```

In ES6 syntax, this function:

```
() => ('test');
```

Equals to

```
() => { return 'test' };
```

So I believe your main problem is because of not understanding exactly the ES6 syntax at the beginning.

You should follow these best practices when it comes to `Promises`:

1. Avoid nesting `catch` in `Promises`
2. Chain `Promises` by returning them and use them in the `then`

Hope it helps.

Comment: you got sth wrong, the second promise block doesnt return Proposals but an advertisement

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I was changed a little your example and I made it work like this: 
`export const create = ({ user, bodymen: { body } }, res, next) =>
  Proposals.create({ ...body, user })
    .then((Proposal) => {
        return Advertisements.findOneAndUpdate(
            {_id:  body.advertisement}, {$push: {proposals: Proposal._id}}
        )
        .then((Advertisement) => Proposal.view())   
    })
    .then(success(res, 201))
    .catch(next)`

Answer (score 0):

The example code is not waiting for, or using the result of the update.

In promises `return`ing a promise and using `.then` waits for that async operation. You can then check the result if required:

```
Proposals.create({ ...body, user })
.then((proposal) => {
    return Advertisements.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id:  body.advertisement}, {$push: {proposals: proposal._id}}
    )
}) 
.then((update) => {
  if (!update) throw new Error(`Could not find advertisement for "${user}"`)
  success(res, 201))
})
.catch(next)
```

Or the equivalent ES2017 code using [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) to wait for the promise to resolve, which should help reason how the above Promise `.then` code flow works.

```
async function handler(){
  try {
    let proposal = await Proposals.create({ ...body, user })
    let update = await Advertisements.findOneAndUpdate(
      {_id:  body.advertisement}, {$push: {proposals: proposal._id}}
    )
    if (!update) throw new Error(`Could not find advertisement for "${user}"`)
    success(res, 201)
  }
  catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: In the second example you're not using Promises, right?

Comment: The second example is Promise based too. [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) waits for the promise to resolve before continuing